# need dos end of line character in unix file, without Unix end of line appended

Tags: unix, text, format, dos

I need to create a dos format text file on Unix, whose end of line character is \r\n.

In Unix and vi, I can see (via "set list") the $ end of line character.
When I convert the file to DOS format using:

```
perl -i -pne "s/\n/\r\n/g" i.txt
```

I get end-of-line as:  ^M$.
This is close, but what I need is a file ending in \r\n (ie: ^M only).

Example i.txt file (say, if have set list enabled in vi):
starting text line one$
starting text line two$

converted produces:
starting text line one^M$
starting text line two^M$

need:
starting text line one^M
starting text line two^M

So I need the dos single-character representation for end of line.  unix2dos didn't help.  Suggestions?

Comment: Do you __really__ want all the text in the file in the same line?  Remove line feeds would put it in a single line.

Comment: Are you trying to tell us typing "dos end of line character in unix" into Google didn't get you an answer?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying :-)  That's where I found the little Perl gem that's mentioned above.  And no, don't want all the text on one line.  Just reading the requirements for this project, and wondering if this is even a possiblity.  I'm thinking "no, must have the \n as well" (ie: can not avoid have both ^M$ at end of every line).  But looking for someone to tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` does not represent a character. It simply shows where the line ends.

The purpose of this is to show trailing whitespace, like in this example explaining `uniq` output:

```
$ uniq file
foo
foo 

$ cat -vE file
foo$
foo $
```

Since it's just a visual marker, asking how to delete it doesn't make sense. It was never there. If you want `\r\n`, then `^M$` is correct. Here's an example of this, verifiable by the hex dump:

```
$ cat -vE file
foo^M$
bar^M$

$ od -c -t x1 < file
0000000   f   o   o  \r  \n   b   a   r  \r  \n
         66  6f  6f  0d  0a  62  61  72  0d  0a
```